# Pretty printing a syntax tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, io, pretty-print

I don't understand this type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO ()'
In the return type of a call of `printv'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: px <- printv x
In the expression:
  do { px <- printv x;
       sep <- print ", ";
       rest <- prints xs;
       return (px : sep : rest) }
```

**From:**

```
data    Value     = IntValue     Int
                  | TruthValue   Bool
                    deriving (Eq, Show)

printv :: Value -> IO()
printv (IntValue   i) = print i
printv (TruthValue b) = print ("boolean" ++ show b)

prints :: [Value] -> [IO()]
prints  []    =  []
prints (x:xs) = do px   <- printv x
                   sep  <- print ", "
                   rest <- prints xs
                   return (px:sep:rest)
```

It looks to me like every element (`px`) is converted into an `IO()` action, and then that is added to a list of the same things, thus producing an `[IO()]` list.

What am I missing here? Converting it to a list of strings, by removing the print's, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the type of your function:

```
prints :: [Value] -> [IO()]
```

But if we now take a look at `prints [] = []`, this can't match, because the type of that one is

```
prints :: [t] -> [a]
```

Therefore, you missed using `prints [] = return []`, to make it work.

Comment: Thanks makes sense - but then just returns: `code`       Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `[a0]'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `[]'
    In the expression: return []
    In an equation for `prints': prints [] = return []

Comment: You are right. `return (px:sep:rest)` is of type `IO [()]` (delete the type signature and the pattern `print [] = []`, then load it into ghci to try it. See the type by using `:i prints`). Therefore, the type of `prints` must be `prints :: [Value] -> IO [()]`. With that, using `print [] = return []` works.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `return` on the `[]` case of `prints`:

```
prints  []    = return []
```

However, your prints is very strange. It returns a `[()]`, because `print` is outputting strings to the console, not returning them.

Do you mean to return strings from your `printv` function?

---

Since you're trying to pretty print a syntax tree, here's roughly the right way to do it:

- Use [pretty-printing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty) combinators
- Use a [pretty typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyclass)

Like so:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint
import Data.List

data Value 
        = VInt   Int
        | VBool  Bool
        deriving (Eq, Show)

class Pretty a where
    pretty :: a -> Doc

instance Pretty Value where
    pretty (VInt i)     = int i
    pretty (VBool b)    = text "Boolean" <+> text (show b)

draw :: [Value] -> String
draw = intercalate ", " . map (render.pretty)

main = putStrLn $ draw [VInt 7, VBool True, VInt 42]
```

Running it:

```
*A> main
7, Boolean True, 42
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not evaluating an IO action, you don't need a `do` block. Just treat `IO ()` as a normal type.

```
prints (x:xs) = printv x : print ", " : prints xs
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `prints` to return an array of IO actions. You want it to return a single IO action that represents each of the IO actions bound together. Something like:

```
prints xs = mapM_ (\x -> printv x >> putStr ", ") xs
```

Except that I don't think the new lines are going to end up where you want them.

Look at the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amapM) for `mapM` and `sequence` for more information. In particular, the [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence) of sequence is probably similar to what you're trying to do.

However, I would really recommend that instead doing all the work in an IO function, you should write a pure function to render the textual format you want, and then just print that. In particular, it seems that an instance of `Show` for `Value` would be appropriate.

```
instance Show Value where
  show (IntValue   i) = show i
  show (TruthValue b) = "boolean " ++ show b
```

That way you can just call `print value` rather than `printv value`, and if you really wanted to you could define `prints` as follows.

```
import Data.List
prints :: (Show a) => [a] -> IO ()
prints = putStrLn . intercalate ", " . map show`.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll redo it - I was just experimenting with using a list of actions, like some early examples in SOE. Trying to earn-the-ropes of IO and do blocks. Once done figuring it all out, I like your Show usage better! Still, I'd like to figure out why my original code fails, even if not so optimal.